# What is difference between xgboost.plot_importance() and model.feature_importances_ XGBclassifier

Tags: python, xgboost, feature-selection, dimensionality-reduction, xgbclassifier

What is difference between xgboost.plot_importance() and model.feature_importances_ in XGBclassifier.

so here I make some dummy data

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# generate some random data for demonstration purpose, use your original dataset here
X = np.random.rand(1000,100)     # 1000 x 100 data
y = np.random.rand(1000).round() # 0, 1 labels
a = pd.DataFrame(X)
a.columns = ['param'+str(i+1) for i in range(len(a.columns))]
b = pd.DataFrame(y)

import xgboost as xgb
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from xgboost import plot_importance
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

model = XGBClassifier()
model.fit(a,b)

# Feature importance
model.feature_importances_

fi = pd.DataFrame({'Feature-names':a.columns,'Importances':model.feature_importances_})
fi.sort_values(by='Importances',ascending=False)


plt.bar(range(len(model.feature_importances_)),model.feature_importances_)
plt.show()

plt.rcParams.update({'figure.figsize':(20.0,180.0)})
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size':20.0})
plt.barh(a.columns,model.feature_importances_)

sorted_idx = model.feature_importances_.argsort()
plt.barh(a.columns[sorted_idx],model.feature_importances_[sorted_idx])
plt.xlabel('XGBoost Classifier Feature Importance')

#plot_importance
xgb.plot_importance(model, ax=plt.gca())
plt.show
```

if you see the graph, the feature importance and plot importance do not give the same result. I try to read the documentation but I do not understand in the layman's terms
so does anyone understand why plot importance does not give results equal to plot importance?

[image: feature_sorted]
[image: bar_sorted]
[image: plot_importance]

if I do this

```
fi['Importances'].sum()
```

I got 1.0, which means that feature importance is the percentage.

if I want to do dimensionality reduction, which feature i should use?
the one that comes from feature importance or plot importance?

Answer (score 1):

The scores you get are not normalized by the total.

Using your example :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xgboost as xgb
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from xgboost import plot_importance
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(99)
X = np.random.rand(1000,100)     # 1000 x 100 data
y = np.random.rand(1000).round() # 0, 1 labels
a = pd.DataFrame(X)
a.columns = ['param'+str(i+1) for i in range(len(a.columns))]
b = pd.DataFrame(y)

model = XGBClassifier(importance_type = "weight")
model.fit(a,b)

xgb.plot_importance(model,max_num_features=10,importance_type = "weight")
```

This is the plot of top 10 most important:

[image]

To get the scores shown on the plot:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(model.get_booster().get_score(importance_type = "weight"),
             index = ["raw_importance"]).T
df[:10]

    raw_importance
param98 35
param57 30
param17 30
param20 29
param14 28
param45 27
param22 27
param59 27
param13 26
param30 26
```

To get back the scores under `model.feature_importances_` , you need to divide the raw importance scores by the sum:

```
    raw_importance  normalized
param98 35  0.018747
param57 30  0.016069
param17 30  0.016069
param20 29  0.015533
param14 28  0.014997
param45 27  0.014462
param22 27  0.014462
param59 27  0.014462
param13 26  0.013926
param30 26  0.013926
```

You will see it's the same as what you have under the model:

```
pd.DataFrame(model.feature_importances_,columns=['score'],index = a.columns)\
.sort_values('score',ascending=False)[:10]

    score
param98 0.018747
param57 0.016069
param17 0.016069
param20 0.015533
param14 0.014997
param45 0.014462
param59 0.014462
param22 0.014462
param12 0.013926
param13 0.013926
```

So to answer your question, to rank the features, you can just use `model.feature_importances_`

Comment: in other words, the `plot_importance` plots the raw values, while the `feature_importances_` provides percentages of the total (i.e. they sum to one)